# jQuery gives wrong value for css left on absolute position

Tags: jquery, firefox

When an element is `position:absolute` and `right:[whatever]`, trying to get `$("#div").css("left")` returns the rendered `left` value, and not `auto` like I'd expect. I've set up a test here: http://jsbin.com/ayesat/1/ In Chrome it alerts "auto", but Firefox alerts a `px` value.

Any way to force Firefox to return whatever is set in the css style?

Comment: Check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5830517/133802) for retreiving the actual CSS styles of an element.

Comment: @DavidHedlund But that seems to give me all the styles? Which is a bit too much. I just want whatever is set as value for `left` in the stylesheet.

Answer (score 1):

You can get what you want if the element is also styled as display:none: that will always return computed styles.

Otherwise, getComputedStyle returns something ... complicated.  See http://dev.w3.org/csswg/cssom/#resolved-value